# dot net core app 3.1 - Error 500 when IIS

Tags: iis, deployment, release, asp.net-core-3.1

Here again because I need some help again and again….
Let me explain you, I have developed an .net core 3.1 API, and everything works well on my environment and in another computer when (in this computer) deployed in IIS.

However, when I deploy on Azure or in Another IIS in a different environment, I’m able to navigate over my API on localhost, but, when I’m try to do the same using the dns I got a 500 http error.

I have done other tests and when my ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Development (on web.config) everything works well from nowhere, however when this value is ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = Release I got again the 500. And the following message on my logs: “[Debug] The request path "" does not match the path filter”. And I did not get no other errors, in logs or in events nothing only this message.

I’ve spent a lot of time with this issue without finding a solution, someone could help me on that please?

Thanks a lot
Best regards
Joao Fernandes

Comment: Hi,
After few searches it seems the bug comes from HSTS, and default configuration. In my case I’ve used a self-signed certificate for my test and the default configuration given in Microsoft website.
So, in that case how can configure it? This couldn’t work with a self-signed certificate? Eve I have used a trusted certificate from my development machine, but the result is the same.
Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Show a full screen shot of the error page please. Keep in mind no one can see your screen.

Comment: Hi, 
In my case the Strict-Transport-Security is added 2 time in the header with 2 different values. I need now to figure out why. So, I’m going to close the question, for sure is an implementing issue.
Thank you to all those that have tried to help me.

Best Regards
Joao Fernandes